# ajax:complete fires but ajax:success doesn't in a rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I am new to RoR, but have decent success with implementing various features for a small app. Until I hit this issue.. for which haven't found any existing issues/questions. To help narrow down my problem to a generic form, here is what I have:

**User Story**

User is presented with a form to create topics (name & description), once topic is created user is presented the 'show' page which allows the user to add subtopics. As the user adds subtopics, they are shown to the user on the same page (this is where I am trying to use ajax).

**Code Artifacts**

model ==> topic_request.rb

```
class TopicRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many   :subtopics, :class_name=>"TopicRequest", :foreign_key=>"parent_id"
end
```

controller ==> topic_requests_controller.rb

```
class TopicRequestsController < ApplicationController
  expose(:user_topic_requests) {current_user.topic_requests}
  expose(:topic_request)
  expose(:sub_topic_request) {TopicRequest.new}

  def new
  end

  def create
    topic_request.save
    if (topic_request.parent_id != nil)
    parentreq = TopicRequest.find(topic_request.parent_id)
    render :partial => 'subreqs', \
           :locals => {:topic_requests => parentreq.subtopics}, \
           :layout => false
    else
    render :show
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def index
  end
end
```

new.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for topic_request, :html => {:class => 'form-stacked'} do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  fieldset
    = f.input :name, :required => true
    = f.input :description, :required => true
  .actions
    = f.button :submit, "Propose Topic"
```

show.html.slim

```
# display the parent topic
= topic_request.name
= topic_request.description

#display the form for accepting subtopic requests
= simple_form_for sub_topic_request, \
                  :url => {:controller => "topic_requests", :action => "create"}, \
                  :remote => true, \
                  :html => {:class => 'form-stacked', \
                            :id => 'new_subtopic_request'} do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  fieldset
    = f.input :name, :required => true
    = f.input :description, :required => true
    = f.input :parent_id, :as => :hidden,\
              :input_html => {:value => topic_request.id}           
  .actions
    = f.button :submit, "Propose Subtopic", \
               :class => "btn", :disable_with => "Please wait..."
#subtopic_requests
  = render :partial => 'topic_requests/subreqs', \
           :locals => {:topic_requests => topic_request.subtopics}
```

partial ==> _subreqs.html.slim

```
- topic_requests.each do |onereq|
  = onereq.name
  = onereq.description
  hr
```

coffeescript ==> topic_requests.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  new_subreq_form = $("#new_subtopic_request")

  if new_subreq_form.length > 0
    new_subreq_form.bind 'ajax:before', (e) ->
      # console.log 'ajax:before'
    new_subreq_form.bind 'ajax:success', (event, data, status, xhr) ->
      $("#subtopic_requests").html(data)
    new_subreq_form.bind 'ajax:failure', (xhr, status, error) ->
      # console.log 'ajax:failure'
    new_subreq_form.bind 'ajax:error', (xhr, status, error) ->
      # console.log 'ajax:error' # parseerror eg
    new_subreq_form.bind 'ajax:complete', ->
      $("#topic_request_name").val("")
      $("#topic_request_description").val("")
```

**Problem**

The subtopic creation happens, I see new records in database. The clearing of fields from 'ajax:complete' binding also happens just fine, I see those input fields clearing up. I see topic_requests/_subreqs.html.slim completing with status 200. The 'show' page however is not showing the results of rendering the partial, which is what I am trying to capture in the 'ajax:success'.

Any ideas to help debug or samples that I refer to do this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

**Rails 4 solution**: add `data {type: 'text'}`:

```
= form_for vendor, :remote => true, data: {type: 'text'}
```

This adds the `data-type="text"` attribute to the form, which [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki) passes to jQuery's `ajax` method as parameter `dataType`.

According to [the docs of jQuery's `ajax` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

- if `dataType` is not specified if is inferred intelligently
- if `json` is inferred, the response is parsed into a Js object and returns a `parse error` on error

This is probably what is happening given the `parseerror` output you get from `'ajax:error'`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I did it works writing explicitly the format type of the request

for example

```
= form_for vendor, :format => :html, :remote => true, :html => {:class => "form form-edit", :'data-widget' => 'edit-vendor-form'} do |f|
```

If I don't use :format in that way then I have the same issue that you have.

I hope help. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In my code I have found that any ajax response needs to specifically include `:content_type => 'text/json'` for `ajax:success` to ever fire. It's weird but unless your response explicitly includes this it seems the browser doesn't always handle it correctly (esp. firefox).

I don't know if you can apply that to fix your situation exactly, but I hope that information helps.